# Need a guide to basic command-line awk syntax

Tags: bash, awk

I have read several awk tutorials and seen a number of questions and answers on here and the *problem* is that I'm seeing a LOT of variety in how people do their awk 1-liners and it has really overcomplicated it in my mind.

So I see things like this:

```
awk '/pattern/ { print }'
awk '/pattern/ { print $0 }'
awk '/pattern/ { print($0) }'
awk '/pattern/ { print($0); }'
awk 'BEGIN { print }'
awk '/pattern/ BEGIN { print };
```

Sometimes I get errors and sometimes not but because I'm seeing so many different phrasings I'm really having trouble fixing syntax errors because I can't figure out what's allowed and what isn't.

Can someone explain this? Does print require parens or not? Are semi-colons required or not? Is BEGIN required or not? What happens when you start an awk script with a /pattern/, and/or just pass it the name of a function like `print` on its own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One at a time:

1. Can someone explain this?

Yes.

2. Does print require parens or not?

`print`, like `return`, is a builtin, not a function, and as such does not use parens at all. When you see `print("foo")` the parens are associated with the string `"foo"`, they are NOT in any way part of the `print` command despite how it looks. It might be clearer (but still not useful in this case) to write it as `print ("foo")`.

3. Are semi-colons required or not?

Not when the statements are on separate lines. Like in shell, semi-colons would be required to separate statements that occur on a single line

4. Is BEGIN required or not?

No. Note that `BEGIN` is a keyword that represents the condition that exists before the first input file is opened for reading so `BEGIN{print}` will just print a blank line since nothing has been read to print. Also `/pattern/ BEGIN` is nonsense and should produce a syntax error.

5. What happens when you start an awk script with a /pattern/, and/or just pass it the name of a function like print on its own?

An awk script is made up of `condition { <action> }` sections with the default condition being TRUE and the default action being `print $0`. So `awk '/pattern/'` means `if the regexp  "pattern" exists in the current record then invoke the default action which is to print that record` and `awk '{ print }'` means `the default condition of TRUE applies so execute the specified action and print the current record`. Not also that `print` by default prints the current record so `print $0` is synonymous with just `print`.

If you are considering starting to use awk, get the book Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins and at least read the first chapter or 2.

Comment: Semi-colons are never required, or are only required to separate multiple action statements? Great answer btw, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Function calls require `()`. Statements do not (but appear to allow them).

[print](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Print) and [printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Printf) are statements so do not require `()` (but supports it "The entire list of items may be optionally enclosed in parentheses.")

From [print](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Print) we also find out that

> The simple statement ‘print’ with no items is equivalent to ‘print $0’: it prints the entire current record.

So we now know that the first three statements are identical.

From [Actions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Action-Overview) we find out that.

> An action consists of one or more awk statements, enclosed in curly braces (‘{…}’).

and that

> The statements are separated by newlines or semicolons.

Which tells us that the semicolon is a "separator" and not a terminator so we don't need one at the end of an action so we now know the fourth is also identical.

`BEGIN` is a [special pattern](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#BEGIN_002fEND) and that

> [a] BEGIN rule is executed once only, before the first input record is read.

So the fifth is different because it operates once at the start and not on every line.

And the last is a syntax error because it has two patterns next to each other without an intervening action or separator.

Answer (score 0):

All of those awk commands (except the last 2) can be shortened to:

```
awk '/pattern/' file
```

since `print` is always the action in `awk`.

Semicolon is optional just before `}`.

You cannot place `BEGIN` after `/pattern/`